# Recursion in yield

Tags: ruby, recursion

So i am trying to do something like this:

```
def func(x,y)
     if x.length == 1 then
         n = x.pop()
         yield(n,y)
     else
         n = x.pop()
         yield(n,func(x,y))
     end
end
```

calling it like:

```
a = func([1,2,3,4,5],0) do |x,y|
    x+y
end
```

Is it possible to do something like this? I keep getting no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError).

I even tried doing something a little different:

```
def func(x,y)
    func(x,y) do |tail|
        ..
    end
end
```

but no luck

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. In almost 6 years of doing Ruby, I have never seen this question pop up before, and now the exact same question gets asked by two different people from (what looks like) two opposite sides of the globe within just 10 hours of other: [Problem with Ruby blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4259652/)

Comment: That is interesting. They are similar questions except mine has the recursive function in the the yield

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can take the block as an argument explicitly:

```
def func(x, y, &block)
```

You can still yield to it with the yield keyword, but you can also pass it as you recurse:

```
yield(n, func(x, y, &block))
```

The `&` in both cases means that the `block` argument is not a normal argument, but represents the block that can be attached to any Ruby method call.

Comment: cool, is there a way to do this without passing the block? Would it be easier to do a loop maybe? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to pass the block in the recursive call.
The recursive call should be like as below:-

```
yield(n,func(x,y)) { |x,y| x+y})
```

Since you missed to pass the block in the recursive call, when the code hits:-

```
     if x.length == 1 then
     n = x.pop()
     yield(n,y) <<<< Here
```

the method func doesn't have block passed as argument,in the recursive call, but ruby tries to call a non-existent block and hence the error.